# database for winform and asp.net

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

Is it possible to use the same database for winform application (with vb.net) and web based with asp.net?

Answer (score 1):

Yes you can always use the same database for windows and web applications. As database is totally a separate from you application.

Answer (score 0):

the database has nothing to do with the application that uses it. Yes it is possible and many applications has windows and web part that uses the same database
BEst Regards,
Iordan

Answer (score 0):

Database is not directly related to the interface you use to access it. With this in mind, then your answer is "yes".

Answer (score 0):

If both applications use the same data, you must not create separate database for each application.

Comment: no..i'm using the same database for both....
right now..i've already build winform and asp.net with same database..it worked fine in my laptop...
but i wonder how to make it work in real..does the database have to upload in web hosting or other..